# How to get display table cell to stretch to remaining height of table in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

Back in the good old days of tables for layout, one could do:

```
<div style="height: 400px;">
<table style="height: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>This cell sizes to its content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="100%">This cell takes up the remaining height.
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>This cell sizes to its content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Now, I'm trying to achieve the same thing using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.  Here is my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/p3jwr/6/

It renders fine in FF and Chrome. Of the 400px the table is supposed to build within, the 1st and 3rd rows each take up 100px, and the 2nd row fills the remaining space, working out to 200px.

In IE9 (and that's the lowest IE I need to support), the second row expands to 400px, which is 100% of the size of the ***table's parent***.  This stretches the table itself to more than 100% of its parent.

The goal here is to have the table stretch to fill its parent, the size of which isn't known, but will definitely be set, and to have the middle row stretch to take up the space not used by the first or third row.

Can anyone propose a workaround for IE?  It doesn't even have to work in the other browsers, but I was hoping to stick with display: table.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
div > table {
        height : auto !important;  
        height : 100%;            
        min-height : 100%;        
    }
```

It applies to most of the browsers.  Check it!

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't achieve the desired effect.  I added the properties from that rule to the style attribute on my table-styled div.  The result looks the same as my original example (but now doesn't work in FF or Chrome either).  http://jsfiddle.net/p3jwr/7/

Answer (score -3):

Try this code,

```
<div style="height: 400px;">
   <table style="height: 100%">
         <tr style="height: 25%">
               <td>This cell sizes to its content</td>
         </tr>
         <tr style="height: 50%">
               <td>This cell takes up the remaining height.
         </tr>
         <tr style="height: 25%">
               <td>This cell sizes to its content</td>
         </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

with the following assumptions,
25% of 400px = 100px
50% of 400px = 200px